# Meanings behind "吹牛" and "拍马屁"

Tags: meaning

I would like to find out more about the two sayings "吹牛" and "拍马屁".

How these sayings come about and get their current meanings?

吹牛 *chuīniú* meaning to brag

拍马屁 *pāimǎpì* meaning to excessively flatter someone

Comment: xiaohouzi79, I removed the 和 in your title so it's all in English. I think the best is to either post in English or in Chinese, but mixing the two might not be the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found something in Baidu Encyclopedia.

For 吹牛

http://baike.baidu.com/view/3806.htm

> Originally 吹牛 comes from 吹牛皮 (blowing cow leather). In the old times,
>   people who lived along the Yellow River used cow leather to make
>   rafts, cuz the yellow river could easily destroy wood boats. However
>   there was no bumpers at that time. So it was strong people who were
>   responsible to blow air into the "leather bag" to make it a raft.
>   However, even the strongest man could not make it by himeself. So if
>   someone says "I can blow a raft by myself", he must be bragging. As a
>   result, people use 吹牛皮 to refer to bragging.

[image: A photo of a 牛皮筏]
The photo comes from: http://www.chinavalue.net/Wiki/%E7%89%9B%E7%9A%AE%E7%AD%8F.aspx

For 拍马屁

http://baike.baidu.com/view/26474.htm

> When it was Yuan dynasty in ancient China, the mongolians loved riding
>   horses (cuz they conquered China and many other places with their
>   cavalry force). At that time, when a mongolian met another mongolian,
>   he would pat the other's horse, and say something like "nice horse".
>   It was the best way to make generals and officers of the Yuan dynasty
>   happy by saying "your horses are good". And when the mongolians ruled
>   China, this custom also came to China.
>
> However, originally it was 拍马 (patting the horse), not 拍马屁.

Forgive my translate ^_^

Comment: Interesting - I'd never thought about the meaning behind these expressions - thanks for the clear insight.

Comment: The picture is hilarious. LOL